# Get rows matching condition across single column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have "Product" table as in BigQuery as shown in the image product.png[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVulA.png)

Question: I want details of all the customers having product 'mac' and all other products. i.e. customer should have product 'mac'

So basically there are three customers having mac - phil, sam, ross

Output table required as shown in image outputrequired.png[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPuiS.png)

I tried two BigQuery standard SQL codes as given below

1) select * FROM `tablename` where product like "%mac" and product like "%windows"
2) select a.custname as custa, a.product as prd_a, a.price as price1, a.buydate as buydate_A, a.price2 as price_2 FROM `tablename` A,`tablename` B 
where a.product like "%mac" and b.product like "%windows"

Query-1: Does not output any data
Query-2: Outputs 27 rows as shown in image: query2output.png[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfnfa.png)

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE custname IN (SELECT DISTINCT custname FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE product = 'mac') 
AND product IN ('mac', 'windows')
```

Another - fancy - way to achieve same

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM UNNEST((
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t) FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  GROUP BY custname HAVING COUNTIF(product = 'mac') > 0
))
WHERE product IN ('mac', 'windows')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mikhail. Really appreciate!!

Comment: Sorry. Being a new user, I didn't knew this. I believe this is now accepted.